# Epsilon-delta proof of $x\sin^2(x)$

Tags: calculus

> Using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of the limit, evaluate $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$, where $f(x) = x\sin^2(x)$ and $a = \infty$.

The limit doesn't exist, so how do I use the definition of the limit to show that a limit doesn't exist? I could prove that the limit doesn't exist by saying that it alternates back and forth and intuitively that makes sense, but how do I make it more rigorous?

Comment: Note that the sequence $x_n=\frac{\pi}{2}(2n+1)$ satisfies $\sin(x_n)^2=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, but $x_n\to\infty$. If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=b$ for some $b\in\mathbb{R}$, then what goes wrong?

Comment: It increases without bound?

Comment: Exactly, $f(x_n)$ tends to $\infty$. So, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ cannot exist.

Comment: A rigorous proof can be easily constructed by contradiction.  Consider the two possible ways it can converge.  Case 1:  Assume the limit goes to some finite value L.  Pick an $\epsilon$ (it doesn't really matter what you pick).  If $f(x)$ converges to $L$ as $x \to \infty$, then there must exist an $x_0$ such that $x > x_0$ implies $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$.  Then, find an $x_1 > x_0$ such that $|f(x_1)-L| > \epsilon$, thereby creating a contradiction and invalidating your assumption that $f(x)$ converges to some finite $L$.  Case 2: the limit is $\pm \infty$.  I'll let you figure this one out.